# i want to install package rave report 5.0 on delphi 7

Tags: delphi, installation, delphi-7, rave-reports

I installed Delphi 7 but Rave report not auto register on pallet component , so i click component -> install packages..-> Click ADD  -> choose RVreport50.bpl but show error "package e:\Delphi7se\Rave5\RVreport50.bpl cant be installed because it is not a design time package".

can anyone help me !

I want install rave report and use on delphi 7 ,i haven't use rave report on delphi before.

Answer (score 0):

The error description is very clear you are try to install a Runtime package, try installing the design time package of rave reports or using the installer of this tool.